# how to search 'axios * /proposal' in vscode ? (like windows file explorer)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to search two word that between them can be any character(s) .
How to search some thing like "wordOne * wordTwo" in vscode search menu ?

Answer (score 1):

I must use :

```
wordOne(.+?)wordTwo
```

Comment: `wordOne.+?wordTwo` would also work, unless you want to use the text inbetween the words